# How to do webix jet navigation?

Tags: webix

I am getting an error in webix jet when I navigate the URL.

The first URL is this => http://localhost:8080/#!/navigationBar/topSideBar/appslist

There is a button to call the next view, After I click the button next view URL(second URL) will => http://localhost:8080/#!/navigationBar/qtoApplication
Then, when I go back(by browser back button) to the first URL view, I got the below error, Url is changed but the view is not changing. I cannot go back to the first URL view.

I tried to add a button at the second URL view in order to go back to the first URL. It is also got the same error as per below.

I used navigationBar view as a top view, the rest is a subview.

I would like to know How to do correct navigation.

Thanks in Advance

```html
myapp.js:9836 TypeError: Cannot read property 'linkInput' of undefined
    at result._init_onchange (webix.js:30753)
    at result.callEvent (webix.js:729)
    at result.render (webix.js:2736)
    at result.render (webix.js:28077)
    at result.$setSize (webix.js:30618)
    at result._set_child_size (webix.js:20648)
    at result._set_child_size (webix.js:20752)
    at result.$setSize (webix.js:20743)
    at result._set_child_size (webix.js:20635)
    at result._set_child_size (webix.js:20752)
```

myapp is like this,

```js
// myapp.js
import { JetApp, EmptyRouter, HashRouter } from "webix-jet";

export default class MyApp extends JetApp {
    constructor(config) {
        const defaults = {
            router: BUILD_AS_MODULE ? EmptyRouter : HashRouter,
            debug: !PRODUCTION,
            start: "/navigationBar/topSideBar/projects"
        };

        super({ ...defaults, ...config });
    }
}

if (!BUILD_AS_MODULE) {
    webix.ready(() => {
        if (webix.CustomScroll){
            webix.CustomScroll.init();           
        }       
        new MyApp().render();
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I would say that there are too few details to tell what exactly is wrong here. As for the stack trace, the error is likely not Jet related, but Webix related. linkInput is the method of a suggest popup. Something is wrong when the view is reinited after you go back to it, I guess it is a view with an input that has a suggest list, or maybe you have a select editor. Could you maybe simplify the structure of your app in a snippet like this  https://snippet.webix.com/jetmenu ? It would be helpful to see what is inside that view that you return to.

Comment: Hello, I really appreciate your help. Below is my code snippet for your reference. I am getting errors when I route back to the previous page. The issue is, if I use a multi combo box I cannot route back, If I remove a multi combo box, I can route back to the previous page. https://snippet.webix.com/xvfmzymg   https://vimeo.com/544904765

Comment: https://vimeo.com/544908541

Comment: Hello, as per webix support, they will reconstruct the issue and fixed in the next build.